# Calculate the algebraic expression in C#

Tags: c#, algebra

Calculate the algebraic expression Z, for which n is inputted by user. Use 2 for loops to solve the problem.

[image]

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int n, k = 1;
            double z;
            float sum, p;
            n = Console.Read();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i+=2)
            {
                sum += p;

                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    p *= (3 * k + 2);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm totally stack in the for loops... any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yea, uh, you're going to have to at least try, here.

Comment: You should be calculating sum += 3k + 2  in the for loop.  I forgot what the "big pie" means next to sigma.  But you gotto add that too of course.

Comment: From the description of the problem, it's hard to tell if you are stuck with the actual math part of this, or the coding part.  If you understand the math portion, try describing the steps you would take to solve this by hand. Once you have a list of steps, begin converting them into code.  We can help with the code part if you get stuck on a specific step, but I think you need to show a little more work first.

Comment: I've tried many times, but I removed the code because I got wrong results in each case..

Comment: At least attempt. Even if it is comments with what you are wanting to do step by step and then some code that shows you attempted.

Comment: Your use of `Console.Read` is incorrect.  You're reading the ascii value of a single character.  You want to read in a line and then convert that to the numeric representation of that number: `int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())` (consider using `TryParse` for user input as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- p has to be initialized to 1 as 0 * X == 0
- Also i and j (why not k) have to be initialized to 1 as it is required by your formula
- You have to sum up the products after the products where calculated as you would add 1 to the correct result otherwise and you would not add the last calculated product

So the code below should give the correct result:

```
        float sum = 0;

        int n = Console.Read();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

          float p = 1;
          for (int k = 1; k <= i+2; k++)
          {
            p *= (3 * k + 2);
          }              

          sum += p;
        }
```

Comment: I get an error -- Use of unassigned local variable 'p' and 'sum'.

Comment: yeah! corrected it! Thought the rest of your code is right :)

Comment: And the answer would be sum, right?